# Git branch push to different repo

Tags: git, branch

I apologize for the stupid question, but I feel like I've really struck a rut with this one.

Currently, I'm hosting my app at PHPFog and to my knowledge they don't allow pushing of any other branch aside from your master branch. My solution was to simply create another app/repo for development.

My question is how can I change my origin specifically on my development branch to push to a separate repo? Or is there a better way to do this entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git remote add dev-origin <dev_repo_url>

$ git push --set-upstream dev-origin dev
```

where `dev` is the name of your development branch.

Comment: would <remote> be the origin? so if my origin is named development it would be `$ git branch --set-upstream dev development`?

Comment: Sorry, I think I had had it set the fetch upstream.  I've revised it to set it for push.